# Powershell Compare value to multiple arrays

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I am trying to compare data to multiple sources and then give me a report of the errors. Due to the changing nature of exceptions, I wanted to build an exception table in csv format that I can change on the fly.

I am going to give the data the best I can and show you what I'm trying to achieve and show you where I'm coming into problems.

The exceptions list holds the prefix to different types of accounts:

```
Exceptions List
_______________
FQ
Q
HQ
E
```

So if my Account was `BND123` then I may have an account called `FQBND123` or `QBND123` I want to be able to add to this list if one of the teams decides they need to make a `JQ` account or anything like that in the future.

This is an example of `Inventoryreport.csv` I'm looking to parse:

```
Safe        Target system user name
HUMAN_ABC       QABC
HUMAN_CDE       QCDE
HUMAN_FGHIJ     QFGHIJ
HUMAN_P123456   root
HUMAN_KLMNO     QKLMNO1
HUMAN_P789123   FQ789123
```

So I am looking to compare target system username to the safe name, and if the leading account is in the exception list, it passes it up, and if it does not, then it throws it as an error.

So in the case of the data above the 2 rows would throw an error below.

```
HUMAN_P123456   root
HUMAN_KLMNO     QKLMNO1
```

Root for obvious reason and the `KLMNO` account because of the trailing `1`.

---

The problem I am getting is that it is saying everything is an error. If I hand type it in to the loop everything is fine.

I had the exceptions in a `foreach` loop too inside the one for the inventory, but it keep looping over the same results and still spitting out everything.

Hopefully this is an OK explanation, I'm sure I'm making this harder than it needs to be.

```
$loc = $scriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$D = $loc + "\Exceptions\Exceptions.csv"
$E = $loc + "\Import\InventoryReport.csv"

$exceptions = Import-Csv -LiteralPath $D 
$inventory = Import-Csv -LiteralPath $E

$list2 = 'Inventory Report Exceptions'
$list3 = 'Target system user name'

$DO = $loc + "\Report\Inventory Report Errors" + "$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).CSV"
$time = (Get-Date).ToString()

foreach ($item in $inventory) {
    $input1 = $item.Safe -replace "HUMAN_"
    $input4 = $item.Safe -replace "HUMAN_P"
    $input2 = $item.$list3
    $input3 = $item.Safe

    if ($input2 -eq ($exceptions.$list2 + $input1) -or $input2 -eq ($exceptions.$list2 + $input4)) {
        return
    }
    else {
        $newitem = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property  @{
            Safe  = $input1
            Owner = $input2
        }| Export-CSV -LiteralPath $DO -NoTypeInformation -append
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit long and not very clear...

Let's look if I got it right:

- I shortened the exceptions list to a regular expression anchored at begin
- simulate the inventory.csv with a here string
- append a column Pass to that
- iterate the entries comparing the split'ed values for equality and save in the new col.

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\02\SO_53109141.ps1
$Inventory = @"
Safe,Target system user name
HUMAN_ABC,QABC
HUMAN_CDE,QCDE
HUMAN_FGHIJ,QFGHIJ
HUMAN_P123456,root
HUMAN_KLMNO,QKLMNO1
HUMAN_P789123,FQ789123
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

#$Exception = [regex]'^(FQ|Q|HQ|E)'
$Exception = [RegEx]("^("+((Import-Csv .\exceptions.csv).'Exceptions List' -join '|')+")")

$Fail = $Inventory | Select-Object *,Pass | ForEach-Object {
   if ( ($_.Safe -split '_P?')[1] -ne ($_.'Target system user name' -split $Exeption)[2]){
       [PSCustomObject]@{
          Safe = ($_.Safe -split '_')[1]
         Owner= $_.'Target system user name'
       }
    }
}
$Fail | Export-Csv '.\new.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
Safe          Target system user name  Pass
----          -----------------------  ----
HUMAN_ABC     QABC                     True
HUMAN_CDE     QCDE                     True
HUMAN_FGHIJ   QFGHIJ                   True
HUMAN_P123456 root                    False
HUMAN_KLMNO   QKLMNO1                 False
HUMAN_P789123 FQ789123                 True
```

**EDIT you can read in the exception from a file:**

```
> import-csv .\exceptions.csv

Exceptions List
---------------
FQ
Q
HQ
E
```

And build a RegEx from the content:

```
$Exception = [RegEx]("^("+((Import-Csv .\exceptions.csv).'Exceptions List' -join '|')+")")
```

Comment: So I am going to try this, is there any way to import the exception list from a CSV, I only ask because the team that will be using this needs simplicity. They can modify a CSV in Excel, probably no so much editing a powershell script. I am going to run a few samples though with how you have it and see how it goes with actual data.

Comment: See changed answer how to construct a RegEx from a read in csv.

Comment: Ok, so a couple of questions with this. I see the statements, and I see how we can use the data. Is there a way to isolate just the false responses? right now its printing everything, with the test data of only 6 lines this is not bad, but my actual report is 4000+, also 2 other quick questions (thank you), will this remove trailing exceptions to? such as if I have ABC_CL, everything that is trailing will have an underscore.

Comment: Edit answer again to output a [PCustomObject] for only the fails into `$Fail` and export that at the end

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to get responses before your edit. Doing it the way your edit is, everything exports and there is no more $_.Pass variable for me to check which one is failing. Thank you again, I am learning so much!

Comment: I just wanted to say I figured out how! Thank you so much, I am very very new to Powershell so learning from people like you helps me grow. Thank you again for your patients and your amazing answer.

Comment: FYI: It may be worth adding `[Regex]::Escape`; i.e. amending `((Import-Csv .\exceptions.csv).'Exceptions List'` to `(((Import-Csv .\exceptions.csv).'Exceptions List' | %{[Regex]::Escape($_)})`; so that if any special characters are included in the values, they don't interfere with the intended logic.

Comment: Ok, I just ran a full real report into this logic to see how it did and I am having a couple of issues. For example there are accounts that start with P, and the ($_.Safe -split '_P?') seems to be splitting them. For example We have legacy accounts that are PVC and PVN but then we have newere accounts that are P123456 is there any way to counter that? My brain says adding another if  $_.Safe.Length -gt 6 then do the P split. But I cant get that to work

Comment: another issue I have is I have accounts like this. Safe = P1234567 and the Target system user name = E1234567_CA is there a way to combat trailing characters in the exception list? I tried adding it and it did not work.

Comment: JonLBevan - I tried to append as you suggested, but it just caused everything to show as false.. not sure if I'm adding it right, this is what it looks like.     $Exception = [RegEx]("^("+((Import-Csv -LiteralPath $D).'Inventory Report Exceptions' -join '|')+")" | %{[Regex]::Escape($_)})

Comment: Ok, I added if($_.Safe.length -gt 12){
$check = ($_.Safe -split '_P?')[1] 
}else{
$check = ($_.safe -split '_')[1]
} which allowed the others to work I just need to figure out how to add the trailing _CA etc to the exceptions list. Thank you all again!

Comment: I have added all the Logic that I know how to do and the only issues I have left are adding the exceptions to the list where its trailing, such as target user name = ABCD_CA

Comment: The list of **new** rules is getting longer and IMO beyonf the scope of a single question.  It's not clear to me how to handle the HUMAN_Pxx and trailing _CA, that should have been part of this question -- or a new question, but only one at a time.

Comment: Thank you LotPings. I have figure out all the issues Except 1. That is in the exception list.There are Target_Systems User Names that have Trailing '_' so something like ABNC_CA, I am not sure if there is a way to include the _ in the exception list. I am currently trying to figure out if I can just split it at the _ because anything after it I don't really care about.

Comment: You could do another split `(... -split '_')[0])` or a `... -replace '_.*$'` on the `Target system user name` when comparing